# JBL Reflect BT bluetooth headset detected as keyboard in 16.04

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

When I connect JBL Reflect BT to Ubuntu Unity 16.04 LTS, it is detected as keyboard and not as a bluetooth headset.

How to resolve this problem. I want to use it as a stereo headset that doubles as a microphone.

Comment: Try deleting and pairing again. Please show us a screenshot  if it happens again and describe what steps you took to pair. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: It just detects the device as a keyboard and opens up options related to keyboard.
I must have deleted / restarted , moved on another X220 / Ubuntu 16.04 (same issue) apart from Lenovo B490  and Acer Windows 10 laptop (works flawless).

Answer (score 2):

So I experienced the same thing and I use a Kali Linux and a JBL bluetooth headset  what I did was I copied the files from a working bluetooth device

`sudo nano /var/lib/bluetooth/EB:D4:3D:F5:C3:32/1C:6B:37:D2:D3:4B/info`

## J-800L (Head set seen as Keyboard)

I changed the class and services

```
Name=J-800L
Class=0x302540 # is the class of a KeyBoard
Services=00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000110d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;

# Services of KeyBoard
```

Copy from

```
 sudo nano /var/lib/bluetooth/EB:D4:3D:F5:C3:32/1B:6E:22:C3:F3:8B/info
```

## Q5 (Working Headset)

```
Name=Q5
Class=0x240404 # is the class of an Headset
Services=0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000110d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;

# Services of an Headset
```

You can just use what I have for Q5 if you don't have a working headset

Then run the :

```
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

or

```
sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service
```

I  hope this was helpful
Although I'd  have to do this every time I want to use the headset which is bad for user experience but then it works so till a better solution pops up manage this one

Comment: This works for ubuntu 20.04 too .. Also, I didnt have another working bluetooth, so I used  the same services tag as in your comment. Worked! :) Thanks for sharing.